# How do I increase a variable until a number is reached in JavaScript, leaving all other spaces blank?

Tags: javascript

I need numbers on a PDF in Adobe Acrobat Pro DC to continue to 30, but in various positions across the PDF pages. Rather than rearrange over and over again (and yet more in the future), I'd rather have a form with autofill boxes extending into the spaces beyond where I need them (think blank monthly calendar spread, filling in those numbers) where I input "1" in one of the boxes and it increases until it gets to 30, leaving the rest of the boxes blank.

What I need help with is getting the numbers to stop there.

Someone else gave me this to get the numbers to increase like I needed:

```
if (this.getField("Box1").valueAsString!="") event.value = 
  Number(this.getField("Box1").valueAsString)+1;
```

<sup>Line break added by editor to reduce scrolling.</sup>

Where this is assigned to the one named `Box2`. That part works beautifully! What I can't figure out is how to tell the numbers to stop at 30. Again, I'm brand spanking new, so I don't really know what I'm doing to begin with.

Some other guys I talked to suggested doing a Date field, but I'm not experienced enough to make the chain of numbers continue and stop where I need them to. That's way beyond me, though I did try with that, too. I'll work up to that one day, but for now I wanted to know if there's a way to code it to stop at a given number, instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to test if the new `event.value` will be more than 30 or not:

```
var stringVal = this.getField("Box1").valueAsString;
if (stringVal !== '') {
  var numVal = Number(stringVal);
  if (numVal < 30) {
    event.value = numVal + 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 0):

slite better solution then @snow answer, take option that user input number bigger than 30

```js
var stringVal = this.getField("Box1").valueAsString;
if (stringVal !== '') {
  var numVal = Number(stringVal);
  event.value = Math.max(numVal + 1, 30);
}
```